# How to find the range of the following function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

> if $f(x)$ is a function such that $|f(x)|\le 1, x \in R \text{ and }$$$ g(x)=\frac{e^{f(x)}-e^{|f(x)|}}{e^{f(x)}+e^{|f(x)|}},$$ then the range of $g(x)$

(a) $[0,1]$

(b)$[0, \frac{1+e^2}{1-e^2} ]$

(c)$[0, \frac{1-e^2}{1+e^2} ]$

(d)$[\frac{1+e^2}{1-e^2},0 ]$

we know that if $|f(x)|\le 1\implies -1\le f(x)\le 1 $. so having the maximum value i.e $f(x)= 1$ and $|f(x)|=1$ we can say that the maximum value of $g(x)=0$

so from this i opted the option (d) but however i am not able to solve for the lower limit. so is the answer is correct because, i don't know the answer of this question ? How do i solve for the lower limit because from this way i can't get the lower limit?

Comment: Are you sure that options b), c) are correctly written ? For example, is it not for c) $ [-\frac{e^2-1}{e^2+1},0]$ ?

Comment: yes. i copied the question exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $f(x)\ge0$ we have $g(x)=0$, since $f(x)=|f(x)|$ and therefore $e^{f(x)}=e^{|f(x)|}$.

When $f(x)<0$ we have $e^{f(x)}<e^{|f(x)|}$ since exponential is increasing function,  therefore $g(x)<0$ and therefore the only correct answer is d.

Comment: @annisaini Isn't the question about the lower limit ?

Answer (score 1):

It is actually impossible to answer the question as a piece of information is missing: the range of $f(x)$. Merely saying that $|f(x)|\le1$ does not guarantee that the whole range $f(x)\in[-1,1]$ is covered.

Anyway, if it is guaranteed that one of the choices holds, notice that $e^{f(x)}\le e^{|f(x)|}$, so that $g(x)\le0$ and the answer must be (d).

You needn't care about the lower limit (achieved for $f(x)=-1$, i.e. $\dfrac{e^{-1}-e}{e^{-1}+e}$, as $g$ is non-decreasing).